# Energy of capacitor

Tags: voltage, capacitor, current, voltage-regulator, battery-charging

[image]

Hi readers, since energy stored in capacitor is given  by the above formula. Does it mean if i use a voltage multiplier connected to capacitor, it will help to increase the maximum amount of energy the capacitor is able to store. Will it explode if too much energy is stored?

Comment: Every capacitor has a maximum allowed voltage, which is usually printed on the capacitor, sometimes encoded as letter. If you exceed it, the cap might explode or catch fire.

Comment: nothing you do to a cap will increase the amount of energy it can safely store.

Answer (score 7):

> Does it mean if i use a voltage multiplier connected to capacitor, it will help to increase the maximum amount of energy the capacitor is able to store.

If you increase the voltage you supply to the capacitor, then it will store more energy, up until the point when ...

> Will it explode if too much energy is stored?

... if you increase the voltage beyond what it is designed for, then the dielectric will break down. A large capacitor may explode when this happens, a small capacitor may fail with no outward sign. X (mains rated) capacitors are designed with effectively fuses in the electrodes to isolate the damage when hit with the expected over-voltage transients present on mains, with a small reduction in their capacitance for each event.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, higher voltage means higher energy stored. Yes, it might explode if too much energy is stored.